# AWS Rate Card and Price List fetching Heap Space error

Tags: java

During AWS price list fetching I am getting heap space error . How can we get rid from that? Its an open source public URL. Can it be possible to store data blockwise from a URL.

I have tried `StringBuffer`, `StringBuilder` and `StringWriter`, but that's of no use:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES, false);
TypeReference<JSONObject> valueTypeRef = new TypeReference<JSONObject>() {
};
json = objectMapper.readValue(new URL(url), valueTypeRef);
```

Using `ObjectMapper` sometimes it is working fine but sometimes it is getting heap space error.

Comment: Can you provide more of your code? What kind of json data are you getting(structurewise)?

Comment: You can get the structure from this url :

https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/index.json

Comment: Your json data is very big, and you are trying to parse all of it at the same time. You should have a look at "processing json with streaming api". You are using Jackson and it supports streaming model.